# Restoring and Activating Windows after changing Bios chip?

Tags: boot, windows-8.1, windows-10, bios

I have an HP Laptop that originally came with a Windows 8.1. I updated to Windows 10 recently. 
However, I was working on my laptop and suddenly it shut downed and didn't boot up again. I tried to restore my bios with the firmware provided in HP site, it didn't work. one of my friends suggested to change my bios chip. I changed the bios chip. 
It booted properly but it was very slow, so I decided to restore it with HP Restore to Factory Setting option (Pressing F11 while booting). It formatted the hard disk and then restarted and it said, "The process stopped". So I tried my HP Recovery Disk, HP Recovery tool said that my Activation code doesn't match. 
What Should I do?

Comment: Your description is too vague. What does "I tried to restore my BIOS" mean? What does "I changed it [my BIOS]" mean? Whe you tried to restore "it", is it your OS? And when you tried your recovery disk, what said your activation code doesn't match? A Windows installer? And what was the exact error message?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I edited the question. I hope I made it clearer.

Comment: Put your original BIOS chip back.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz It doesn't boot. It gets to restart loops.

Comment: How far does it get in the booting process before it restarts? Details really matter.

Comment: It shows HP logo. After 15 to 20 seconds it restarts. If I press F11 very fast It shows the Recovery Option but its restart again.

Comment: Run the hardware diagnostics from the original; bios.